# UDP Client Source port in C?

Tags: c

I am writing a UDP client and I need to mention the source port of my UDP packet in my data to send.

1. How my program can get the random port number generated by kernal which udp client is using to send data to voip server. 
   so
2. How can i specify a specific UDP source port before sending data.

I will be very very thankful. Please reply me as soon as possible. My project is stopped at this point.

Answer (score 8):

Use `bind` to bind your socket to port 0, which will allow you to use `getsockname` to get the port. you can also bind your socket to a specific port, if you wish.

eg (assuming IPv4 socket, no error checking):

```
struct sockaddr_in sin = {};
socklen_t slen;
int sock;
short unsigned int port;

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
sin.sin_port = 0;

bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin));
/* Now bound, get the address */
slen = sizeof(sin);
getsockname(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, &slen);
port = ntohs(sin.sin_port);
```

Alternately, if you are communicating with a single server, you can use `connect` on your UDP socket (which also gives you the handy side effect of allowing you to use `send` instead of `sendto`, and making the UDP socket only accept datagrams from your "connected" peer), then use `getsockname` to obtain your local port/address. You may still choose to bind your socket prior to using `connect`.

eg:

```
struct sockaddr_in sin = {};
socklen_t slen;
int sock;
short unsigned int port;

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
/* set sin to your target host... */
...
connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin));
/* now retrieve the address as before */
slen = sizeof(sin);
getsockname(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, &slen);
port = ntohs(sin.sin_port);
```

Comment: I am not able to solve the problem can you gime some code segment.

Answer (score 2):

You should `bind(2)` your socket to a port of your choosing. See also
`man 7 ip` and `man 7 udp`.

Comment: Show first you non-working code and explain in what way it did not work (error code, unexpected behavior...).